# Is there any way to find ignored rows during mysql update ignore query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to bulk update in a table. Table also have a unique constraint on three columns.

I want to use `update ignore` statement of MySQL to avoid duplicate key error and at the same time I want to get the rows which were ignored during the operation.

I have tried `show warnings` query, but it returns empty array.

Is there any way by which I can get those rows?

Thanks

Comment: *Is there any way by which I can get those rows?* Do it before updating by according SELECT statement (table INNER JOIN rowset for updating). But this method cannot show ignored rows if they become duplicates due to previous updating.

Comment: Alternatively use BEFORE UPDATE trigger which checks the values for duplicating and, if so, saves them to some service table.

Comment: @Akina could you help me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,11), (2,22);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |  11
>  2 |  22
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ignored_rows (id INT, val INT);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER save_ignored_rows
> BEFORE UPDATE
> ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
>                 FROM test
>                 WHERE id = NEW.id ) THEN
>         INSERT INTO ignored_rows VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.val);
>     END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
> -- no violation
> UPDATE IGNORE test SET id = 3 WHERE val = 11;
> SELECT * FROM test; SELECT * FROM ignored_rows;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  2 |  22
>  3 |  11
>
> id | val
> -: | --:
> ```

> ```
> -- violation
> UPDATE IGNORE test SET id = 2 WHERE val = 11;
> SELECT * FROM test; SELECT * FROM ignored_rows;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  2 |  22
>  3 |  11
>
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  2 |  11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9258000512065dda6839c0036739354b)*